# Why BYTEA is considered as TEXT format?

Tags: postgresql

I'm debugging an app about a streaming problem from my database.

Turning my client logs to finest level I figure out that Postgres sent column descriptions metadata with the **TEXT_FORMAT** byte (the *T* flag) for **BYTEA** type (see [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L2640) for the class generating log's code source) :

```
02/08/2022 15:32:54.907 [TRACE] o.p.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl - Field(fichier2_18_0_,BYTEA,65535,T)
```

I need a binary format from Postgres, if *BYTEA* is not considered as a binary type, which one can I try to use?

Comment: `bytea` **is** a binary data type. However it is sent over the wire using different text _representations_. The default representation can be controlled through [bytea_output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT)

Comment: `bytea` is a BLOB data type, unrelated to characters.

Comment: Since it looks like you are using the Postgres JDBC driver have you looked at [Binary data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html)?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes I implement my client with it. But if I understand this type consideration I hope to be able to implement it with hibernate layer. At the moment I'm not relayy confident...

Comment: Confident of what? You have yet to explain what the issue is?